# How do you add a database to a C# Project?

Tags: c#

I'm trying to use Linq on this project. Therefore I need the database to show up in Database Explorer so I can use the Object Relational Designer.

I've done this before (I think) but this time it won't work and I don't know why.

1. right click and add connection
2. change data source to Microsoft SQL Server Database File
3. how do i select the database?

correction - i just let it create the database but now I dont know how to open it in sql server.

Comment: Which database server you're going to work with? MSSQL? SQLCE? maybe a MS Access file? If you're going to use MSSQL, have you created the database prior to adding it's connection string using the Server Explorer?

Comment: mssql - i can create it myself but i dont know how to point to it. if i let vs create it i don't nkow how to open it with sql server

Comment: this is actually the answer http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20071221220201AA9W2mG

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the Service  "SQL Server (MSSQLSERVER)" is stopped so please go to Services and start. Once it has started then retry connecting it